# Decode BLE Temperature characteristics value to Celsius

Tags: android, encoding, character-encoding, bluetooth-lowenergy, arraybuffer

I am using a BLE device to read temperature and get it on my system, but
I am stuck on how to parse the encoded value returning from temperature characteristics value.

for eg: I am getting `BmsBAP/aBwECAR8AAA==` in response from the BLE device, and I am supposed to convert it to exactly `36.3 degree Celsius`.
some more readings are:

Characteristics value: `BmsBAP/aBwECAR8AAA==`     Device Reading: 36.3 C

Characteristics value: `BmwBAP/aBwECASEAAA==`     Device Reading: 36.4 C

Characteristics value: `BmYBAP/aBwECAR0AAA==`     Device Reading: 35.8 C

BLE device used: FORA IR20 Infrared Thermometer

here is a snippet of code which I tried: https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-92jt2g?file=index.ts

So, need help to find out the correlation between the required temperature and the encoded value being sent from the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*BmYBAP/aBwECAR0AAA==*" is encoded using Base64 and the hex rappresentation of decoded data is

- 0x06 0x66 0x01 0x00 0x07 0x01 0x02 0x01 0x1D 0x00 0x00

You're saying that it stays for "35.8°C" and usually raw data is stored without decimal, so it became "358".
358 could be rapresented as

- 0x166

As you can see "1", "6" and "6" is present in the initial bytes in "0x66" and "0x01" so you can read/reorder initial bytes like this:

1. "0x06" seems always the same for all and I don't know what it could be. Maybe the measument unit ID
2. 0x01 + 0x66 = 0x166 which is 358 = 35.8°C

If you do same procedure for the others you will get:

- "*06 6C 01 00 07 01 02 01 21 00 00*" for "36.4°C" = 0x01 + 0x6C = 0x16C = 364
- "*06 6B 01 00 07 01 02 01 1F 00 00*" for "36.3°C" = 0x01 + 0x6B = 0x16B = 363

Answer (score 0):

By Using ChatGpt:
Maybe it will help.

It looks like there are a couple of issues in your code:

1. The values in `vals` seem to be Base64-encoded strings, but your `base64ToArrayBuffer` function is attempting to use the `atob` function, which is designed for decoding Base64-encoded strings to binary data. Since your values are already Base64-encoded, you should directly decode them using `Base64` decoding. Here's the corrected `base64ToArrayBuffer` function:

```js
function base64ToArrayBuffer(base64) {
  var binaryString = window.atob(base64);
  var bytes = new Uint8Array(binaryString.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < binaryString.length; i++) {
    bytes[i] = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return bytes.buffer;
}
```

2. In the loop where you're trying to extract the value using `DataView`, you are using `getUint8(1)`, but this may not be correct based on the actual format of your data. If the temperature is represented as a floating-point number, you might need to use `getFloat32` or `getFloat64` depending on the precision. Here's an example assuming the temperature is a 32-bit floating-point number:

```js
vals.forEach((val) => {
  const bs64ArrBuff = base64ToArrayBuffer(val);
  const view = new DataView(bs64ArrBuff);
  
  // Assuming the temperature is a 32-bit floating-point number (4 bytes)
  const temperature = view.getFloat32(0, true); // true for little-endian, adjust based on your device's endianness
  console.log(val, '==>>', temperature);
});
```

Please adapt the code based on the actual data format used by your BLE device. If the temperature is stored differently (e.g., as an integer or in a different byte position), you may need to adjust the `getUint8` or `getFloat32` accordingly. Check the device documentation for the correct interpretation of the data.